# Integrate IBM App Id with a R Shiny CF app

Tags: shiny, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-appid

I have a R Shiny app running as a Cloud Foundry app in IBM Cloud. However there is currently no security around this and its exposed publicly. I have been looking at the IBM Cloud App Id service and I believe that it could be used somehow.

I have been looking at the App Id (https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/app-id) and it seems to make sense. I can create a node app using the sample and that all works fine. I don't know how I can use this to secure my R Shiny app though.

There appears to be an app section where you can generate credentials for a new app but not sure how to use this.

Many thanks for any assistance

Comment: Please add links or code to "there appears to be an app section".

Comment: So this is in the IBM cloud dashboard. Basically can generate a new app credentials that contain a new secret etc. Presumably this gets linked with the app code that is being secured somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I am working in a package to get authentication with App ID IBM service in the Shiny Apps. The repository is [here](https://github.com/th1460/appId).

### Example

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)
require(appId)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(user_info(), # show user info
                  title = "My dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # if you want get user info in app
  userinfo <- callModule(get_user_info, "userinfo")
  output$user <- renderText({userinfo()})

}

# modified shinyApp
shinyAppId(ui, server)
```